# Training Keras models in parallel in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, deep-learning

\I'm trying to train multiple Keras models in parallel using Apache Spark and Elephas. Here's the code for what I'm trying to do:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv("csv_files/stats.csv")
timesteps = 30

model_1, rdd1 = train_LSTM_model(spark_context = sc, dataframe= train_data, column_number=1 ,timesteps = 30)
model_2, rdd2 = train_LSTM_model(spark_context = sc, dataframe = train_data, column_number=2,timesteps = 30)
model_3, rdd3 = train_LSTM_model(spark_context = sc, dataframe = train_data, column_number=3,timesteps = 30)
model_4, rdd4 = train_LSTM_model(spark_context = sc, dataframe = train_data, column_number=4,timesteps = 30)
model_5, rdd5 = train_LSTM_model(spark_context = sc, dataframe = train_data, column_number=5,timesteps = 30)
model_6, rdd6 = train_LSTM_model(spark_context = sc, dataframe = train_data, column_number=6,timesteps = 30)
# Fitting model to RDD
spark_model_1 = fit_to_spark_model(keras_model=model_no_programs_run, rdd = rdd1)
spark_model_2 = fit_to_spark_model(keras_model=model_duration_time, rdd = rdd2)
spark_model_3 = fit_to_spark_model(keras_model=model_avg_duration_time, rdd = rdd3)
spark_model_4 = fit_to_spark_model(keras_model=model_no_processed_records, rdd = rdd4)
spark_model_5 = fit_to_spark_model(keras_model=model_status_states, rdd = rdd5)
spark_model_6 = fit_to_spark_model(keras_model=model_failure_within_period, rdd = rdd6)


# HOW TO RUN THE SCRIPT
#spark-submit --driver-memory 1G ./stats_app.py
```

Alot of the code is abstracted away, but basically the `train_LSTM_model()` function is returning a compiled Keras model, along with an RDD. The rdd_1, rdd_2, rdd_# etc, is from :
`rdd = to_simple_rdd(spark_context, X_train, y_train)` inside of the function. The X_train and y_train has been extracted from the passed in dataframe into each `train_LSTM_model()` function.

Also, here is what the `fit_to_spark_model()` function is doing:

```
def fit_to_spark_model(keras_model, rdd):
   spark_model = SparkModel(keras_model, frequency='epoch', mode='asynchronous')
   spark_model.fit(rdd, epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_split=0.25)
   return spark_model
```

Does this make sense for training multiple Keras models at the same time on Spark Worker nodes? Or would I have to take a different approach? Not sure if I need just one RDD or multiple like I'm currently doing. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand the working of Spark & Elephas fully before implementing it. If these steps you did is to create parallelization by Spark, then let me clarify that this is absolutely unnecessary. Parallelism is achieved internally spark without any explicit coding from user end.

train_LSTM_model() - this returns a Keras model & creates an rdd using `to_simple_rdd` method of Elephas.

From basic documentation of Elephas, I suspect all the rdd's & models returning from the `train_LSTM_model` function will be same(if you are not doing any changes to the dimensions of the data in train_LSTM_model code block). So, you will end up building similar models on the same dataframe multiple times.

Even if my premise that models & data are same is wrong, I suggest you to run each model individually as this may clog up the spark server, potentially not releasing enough worker nodes to each model, ending up taking each run of model a lot of time.